# How to set selected first cell by default in SASlideMenu?

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview, saslidemenu

I am using this script for slide menu "[SASlideMenu](http://www.cocoacontrols.com/platforms/ios/controls/saslidemenu)" and I am trying to select the first item by default, but with no success. Does anybody know how to do it?

I tried this:

```
(void) viewDidLoad{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    ...

    self.tableView.delegate = self;
    NSString *CellIdentifier = @"homeCell";
    UITableViewCell *homeCell = [self.tableViewdequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier]; 
    [homeCell setSelected:YES];

}
```

**UPDATE (improved explanation)**

I am doing this in "SASlideMenuViewController.m"

**UPDATE 2**

Further to main question I would like to ask when user enters applicationWillEnterForeground how to select then first cell and switch to home page?
P.S. I dont want to open another question for that, because it could be treated like a "duplicate".

**UPDATE 3**
I don't know how to switch to home page when user is on another view. For example we switch user to home page when he came back to app(foreground), but this doesn't work in next situation; in SASlideMenu I have list of categories and when I go to one of this categories and then exit from app and back again into app, it switch me to home page and that's ok. But when I click on one of categories in SASlideMenu and then click inside of category view on one of articles and exit app and enter again then it does not  switch me to home page and I don't know why. It's navigation based app.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Question 1: To select the first item by default on launch of app

Assuming that you are using the `SASlideMenu` code mentioned in the question. In your `ExampleMenuViewController` class you need to add the following,

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];

    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0];
    if (indexPath) {
        [self.tableView selectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:NO scrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionNone];
    }
}
```

***_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_***

### Question 2: To select the first item by default and to set home screen in `applicationWillEnterForeground`

Add the following method declaration in your `ExampleMenuViewController.h` file,

```
@interface ExampleMenuViewController :SASlideMenuViewController<SASlideMenuDataSource>

- (void)selectFirstRowAndSetHomePage;

@end
```

Add the following method in your `ExampleMenuViewController.m` file,

```
- (void)selectFirstRowAndSetHomePage {

    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0];
    if (indexPath) {
        [self.tableView selectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:NO scrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionNone];
    }

    NSString *identifier= [self.slideMenuDataSource initialSegueId];
    if (identifier) {
        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:identifier sender:self];
    }
}
```

Implement the following in your `SASlideMenuAppDelegate.h` class,

```
#import "ExampleMenuViewController.h"
```

And,

```
- (void)applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication *)application {

    ExampleMenuViewController *exampleMenuViewController = (ExampleMenuViewController *)self.window.rootViewController;
    [exampleMenuViewController selectFirstRowAndSetHomePage];
}
```

That should help.

***_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_***

Comment: It would be great if you could tell me one more thing. When I'm in of views and I want to on tap of button to back home, ho to do that? I tried with: -(void)backToHomePage{
    
    ExampleMenuViewController *exampleMenuViewController = (ExampleMenuViewController *)self.view;
    [exampleMenuViewController selectFirstRowAndSetHomePage];
    
} But it doesn't work.

Comment: @CroiOS, What is the issue you are facing, can you post as a different question? Probably we can have a look at your exact issue which you are facing.

Comment: Try adding [self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:NO]; before the line NSString *identifier= [self.slideMenuDataSource initialSegueId]; Check if that works. Basically you might have to go to rootview.

Comment: It jump's for a half of second on home view and then come's back to article again.

Comment: @CroiOS, In that case you might have to create it as a separate method and keep only this line instead of the last initialSegueId line.

Answer (score 1):

This should work for you:

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0];
    [self.tableView selectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:NO scrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionNone];
}
```

Comment: Working, nice. One more thing, please take a look at my "UPDATE 2" which I was added before bounty started. How can I switch to home View (default view) after user enters applicationWillEnterForeground?

Answer (score 0):

Check with this code:

```
NSIndexPath *indexPath = [[NSIndexPath alloc] initWithIndex:0];
UITableViewCell *homeCell = [[self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath] setSelected:YES];
```

Comment: @CroiOS: where did you write the code ? write it in the viewDidAppear.

Comment: -(void) viewDidAppear{
    
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [[NSIndexPath alloc] initWithIndex:1];
    UITableViewCell *homeCell = [self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    [homeCell setSelected:YES];
    
}

Comment: Thank you very much. If you could check please too in that example how could I when user enter applicationWillEnterForeground to switch to default home page.

Answer (score 0):

When `viewDidLoad` is called your table is still empty. You are not even taking a cell which is inside the table.

Try this code:

```
NSIndexPath firstCellIndex = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0];
[self.tableView selectRowAtIndexPath:firstCellIndex
                            animated:NO 
                      scrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionNone];
```

And put it into `viewDidAppear`.

Comment: Not working. I am doing this in "SASlideMenuViewController.m"